# Windows 7 x64, Intel HD 4000 took 2 GB of ram. Why?

Tags: windows-7, memory, drivers, integrated-graphics

The last week I installed Windows 7 Professional x64 on my notebook, and after installing some drivers I noticed that only 5.86 GB of 8 GB of RAM was being used. I did a little research, and I found that the Intel HD 4000 graphic card tooks up to 2 GB of RAM.

Before installing Windows, I was using Xubuntu, and in that moment, the graphics card tooks up to 256 MB.

But if I boot up from Linux now, the graphics card keeps the 2 GB of RAM. So, it's not a Windows thing.

I already search a option in the bios for this, but I found none.

So, how, and why, the graphics cards tooks 2 GB of RAM?

Some screenshots.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Thanks for the help!

Comment: If you want to add screenshots, then please [edit] your question and add plain links, we'll embed them for you.

Comment: I was trying, and I endep up creating an album in my onedrive. I can put the links if you want. Thanks.